# Is "Closing the loop" generally understood?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I am currently looking for a slogan on the topic of recycling.

Therefore, I found also this ELU topic:
[Meaning of phrase "to close the loop on this"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301527/meaning-of-phrase-to-close-the-loop-on-this)

I want to ask, if it is common or at least understandable to say "closing the loop" or "I close the loop". In recycling we often talk about circularity or circular economy, but "closing the circularity" sounds bad.

Comment: Used in family planning clinics I believe.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=close+the+loop&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclose%20the%20loop%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cclose%20the%20loop%3B%2Cc0), it's definitely a common phrase in modern usage. It has the downside of being a widely mocked corporate-speak cliché, but it helps that you're using it in a punning way. If that humor is obvious it would be a benefit.

You could also pursue other idioms or phrases. "Circle back" is even more recognized as a cliche, but "bring full circle" is less charged and has more use in broad contexts. "What goes around comes around" carries karmic connotations that might be appropriate. "In the loop" conveys hip knowledgeability.

Comment: And the cycle in recycle is a circle.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The phrase may be commonly used, but it requires a context to convey something; without a context, it will not be obvious what the relevant loop is, and how it is to be closed. So, to respond to the OP's concerns directly: one should not assume that one's audience will understand the phrase in the way in which it is intended, unless the context clearly point to that interpretation. The most highly upvoted answer to the question that the OP provided a link to is about very different loops and very different closings than what the OP has in mind.